# Serre duality in Cech cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth Riemann Surface (to be simple) and let $E\longrightarrow X$ be a coherent sheaf. The Serre Duality states that there exists a pairing 
$$
H^1(X,E) \otimes H^0(X, E^\vee \otimes K_X) \longrightarrow H^1(X,K_X)\simeq \mathbb C
$$
This is usually (at least where I read) done in terms of a resolution of $E$ or using the Dolbeault cohomology when $E$ is a vector bundle.

**My question is whether this pairing can be computed in terms of Cech cohomology.**

It seems that for a acyclic cover $\{ U_i \}$ 
$$
(U_i\cap U_j , s_{ij}) \otimes (U_i, f_i \otimes \omega_i) \mapsto (U_i\cap U_j , f_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}(s_{ij})\omega_i|_{U_i\cap U_j})
$$
must work but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is that your $1$-cochain is well-defined. So does $\sigma_{ij}=f_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}(s_{ij})\omega_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$ equal $f_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}(s_{ij})\omega_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}$? (Well, recall that $\{f_i\otimes\omega_i\}$ is a $0$-cocycle.) Then it's a matter of checking that $\{\sigma_{ij}\}$ define a $1$-cocycle: You compute the coboundary $\sigma_{ij}-\sigma_{ik}+\sigma_{jk}$ on $U_i\cap U_j\cap U_k$. If you use the fact that $\{s_{ij}\}$ is a $1$-cocycle, this all turns to $0$.

(It's probably best to assume $i<j<k$ in these computations. But if not, we have, e.g., $s_{ij}=-s_{ji}$ for a $1$-cocycle. Then $\sigma_{ji}=f_j|_{U_j\cap U_i}(s_{ji})\omega_j|_{U_j\cap U_i} = -f_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}(s_{ij})\omega_i|_{U_i\cap U_j} = -\sigma_{ij}$, as is consistent.)

Comment: Any idea to prove it is a nondegenerate pairing?

Comment: This is a deeper, global result. The usual proof for compact complex manifolds uses Hodge theory. You might look at Forster's lovely book on Riemann Surfaces to see a proof based on residues and Riemann-Roch.

Comment: I'm aware of those proofs. The question is exacly how to do it in Cech cohomology.

Comment: Maybe you can try to modify Bott-Tu’s Cech-flavored proof  of Poincaré duality. I haven’t thought about it.